# Having trouble with SD Card Copier

Tags: usb, boot, sd-card, video

I put my USB on my pi and open SD Card Copier. I select the pi's sd card and the output device to my usb (dev/sda) and I click start: I notice on the file manager it creates a ~280MB partition and then when it tries to create another one it says: Cannot create partition. I look at my USB and now it doesn't appear on the file manager. Gparted opens it as read only now. and also on dmesg I get this after trying to do the same process:

```
[   81.372204]  sda:
[   82.092106]  sda: sda1
[   82.819981]  sda: sda1
[   88.208813]  sda: sda1 sda2
[   89.411161]  sda: sda1 sda2
[   91.119798] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[   91.119809] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x7 [current] 
[   91.119817] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x27 ASCQ=0x0 
[   91.119827] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 08 20 28 00 00 f0 00
[   91.119836] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 532520 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[   91.119845] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 5, lost async page write
[   91.119860] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 6, lost async page write
[   91.119874] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 7, lost async page write
[   91.119887] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 8, lost async page write
[   91.119901] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 9, lost async page write
[   91.119914] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 10, lost async page write
[   91.119928] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 11, lost async page write
[   91.119942] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 12, lost async page write
[   91.119955] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 13, lost async page write
[   91.119968] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 14, lost async page write
[   91.120996] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[   91.121004] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x7 [current] 
[   91.121011] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x27 ASCQ=0x0 
[   91.121019] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 08 21 18 00 00 f0 00
[   91.121028] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 532760 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[   91.122122] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[   91.122129] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x7 [current] 
[   91.122137] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x27 ASCQ=0x0 
[   91.122145] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 08 22 08 00 00 f0 00
[   91.122153] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 533000 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[   91.123246] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[   91.123253] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x7 [current] 
[   91.123261] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x27 ASCQ=0x0 
[   91.123268] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 08 22 f8 00 00 f0 00
[   91.123276] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 533240 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[   91.124337] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[   91.124345] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x7 [current] 
[   91.124352] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x27 ASCQ=0x0 
[   91.124359] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 08 23 e8 00 00 f0 00
[   91.124367] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 533480 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[   91.126396] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[   91.126406] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x7 [current] 
[   91.126413] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x27 ASCQ=0x0 
[   91.126421] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 08 24 d8 00 00 f0 00
[   91.126431] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 533720 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[   91.127547] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[   91.127555] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x7 [current] 
[   91.127562] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x27 ASCQ=0x0 
[   91.127570] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 08 25 c8 00 00 f0 00
[   91.127578] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 533960 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[   91.128685] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[   91.128692] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x7 [current] 
[   91.128699] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x27 ASCQ=0x0 
[   91.128707] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 08 26 b8 00 00 f0 00
[   91.128715] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 534200 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[   91.130388] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[   91.130396] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x7 [current] 
[   91.130403] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x27 ASCQ=0x0 
[   91.130412] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 08 27 a8 00 00 f0 00
[   91.130421] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 534440 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[   91.131544] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[   91.131551] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x7 [current] 
[   91.131558] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x27 ASCQ=0x0 
[   91.131566] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 08 28 98 00 00 f0 00
[   91.131574] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 534680 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Is my usb failing?
I am open to suggestions.

Regs.

Answer (score 1):

The `SD Card Copier` has problems with some SD Cards, as it performs file copies and is intolerant of errors.

It MAY be possible to use the SD Card if you format with the SDFormatter.app but it is probable that the SD Card is worn out.